# Why is my python udf returning empty output in redshift?

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I have a table with a column containing datetime values with different_formats - with millisecond, without millisecond, with zero padding, without zero padding.
I need to use that data to calculate the time intervals. So, I wrote a python UDF fuunction and tried calling that in my query. But I get empty values when called on the table and error when called with a string.
My UDF function is:

```
create or replace function everyonesdb.validateDate(tzDate varChar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
    from datetime import datetime
    try:
        return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(tzDate,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f %z'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z')
    except ValueError:
        pass
$$ language plpythonu;
```

I am calling it like this:

```
Select validateDate('2018-04-19 09:29:52 +1000')
```

Error I am getting:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: function validatedate("unknown") is not unique;
```

I tried it within my query also. With this I just get null values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT date_time_tz,
   validateDate(date_time_tz) from table1
```

O/P:

```
     date_time_tz                   validatedate
    2018-04-19 12:37:33:359 +0800   
    2018-04-19 10:23:27:492 +1000   
    2018-04-19 11:02:58:810 +1000   
    2018-04-19 09:39:42:820 +1000   
    2018-04-19 10:30:18:017 +0530   
    2018-04-19 16:14:49:581 +1000
```

This is my first time trying a Python UDF. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pass` on error is *extremely* bad form. At a bare minimum, make the `return None` in that case explicit so that it's clear you intended to do so. That said, I don't see the logic behind returning `NULL` on error here. Such an error likely indicates malformed data, in which case the error should be raised back to the caller. If you're trying to categorize dates as valid or invalid, your function should probably return a *boolean*, not the date or `NULL`. Consider, for example, that the input date might itself be `NULL`; your function can't distinguish between `NULL` inputs and invalid inputs.

Comment: @jpmc26: Thanks for replying. I agree it is not the best way. But I am just trying my options out. If it works out, I will improve the return statements. This is not going to production environment for now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In

`validateDate('2018-04-19 09:29:52 +1000')`

the string is not recognized as varchar for some reason (probably mapping of data types between SQL and Python). Try specifying the data type explicitly to avoid that issue

`validateDate('2018-04-19 09:29:52 +1000'::varchar)`

In the query, you use the function on datetime, looks like it accepts the datetime as varchar parameter but the code throws the exception and ends on `pass` line, returning null. Try doing the same with the second query (add `::varchar`)

Comment: Thanks for replying @AlexYes. I tried casting the input to varchar. I don't get any error now but the output still continues to be Null.

Comment: @IshaGarg does your function work in Python with the same input?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, modify as needed. Not sure *exactly* what is wrong with yours.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_validate_date(tz_date VARCHAR(50))
    RETURNS TIMESTAMP
STABLE
AS $$
    if tz_date is None:
        return None
    else:
        from datetime import datetime
        dtm = datetime.strptime(tz_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%f')
        return dtm
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu
;
```

Results

```
SELECT f_validate_date('2018-05-01 18:18:00:000');
   f_validate_date
---------------------
 2018-05-01 18:18:00
```

Or you could do it the old fashioned way. It's faster but doesn't like a semicolon milliseconds separator.

```
SELECT '2018-05-01 18:18:00.000'::TIMESTAMP;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2018-05-01 18:18:00

--Leading zeroes
SELECT '0002018-05-01 18:18:00.000'::TIMESTAMP;
      timestamp
---------------------
 2018-05-01 18:18:00
```

Comment: See https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-redshift-udfs/ for working examples of Redshift UDFs.